# OpenCV Camera calibration use of rotation matrix

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera

I used cv::calibrateCamera method with 9*6 chessboard pattern. 
Now I am getting rvecs and tvecs corresponding to each pattern,
Can somebody explain the format of rvecs and tvecs?
As far as I have figured out it is each one is 3*1 matrix.
and OpenCV documentation suggests to see Rodrigues function.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

As far rodrigues is concerned it is way to rotate a vector
around a given axis with angle theta.
but for this we need four values unit Vector(ux,uy,uz) and the angle. but openCV seem to use only 3 values.

OpenCV rodrigues documentation refer the below link [http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void Rodrigues(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, OutputArray jacobian)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20Rodrigues%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian%29)

says that it will convert 3*1 matrix to 3*3 rotation matrix.
Is this matrix same as which we use 3D graphics.
can I convert it to 4*4 matrix and use it for transformations like below

M4X4 [

x x x 0

x x x 0

x x x 0

0 0 0 1

]

x : are the values from output 3by3 matrix of rodrigues function.
Is the relationship valid:

Vout = M4X4 * Vin;
using the matrix above.

Answer (score 1):

The 3x1 rotation vector can express a rotation matrix by defining an axis of rotation via the **direction** that the vector points and an angle via the **magnitude** of the vector. Using the opencv function `Rodrigues(InputArray src, OutputArray dst)` you can obtain a rotation matrix which fits the function you describe.